# jQuery + handlebars IE8 value attribute contains other attribute

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, handlebars.js

I am using Handlebars.js and jquery to retrieve an HTML temlate and render it.
In different browsers (IE10, IE9, FF, Safari, Chrome) this works perfectly.

However, when using IE8 this doesn't work well at all.
I am trying to render a form with input fields. The fields do turn up in the page,
but the value attribute is filled with another attribute.

Per example:

```
<input id="lastName" autocomplete="off" required="" value="name=lastName"/>
```

And I would expect:

```
<input id="lastName" autocomplete="off" required="" value="" name="lastName" />
```

In the template this looks like":

```
<input id="lastName" autocomplete="off" required="" value="{{lastName}}" name=lastName/>
```

This only happens when the variable lastName, which need to be loaded by handlebars, is empty. When this variable is not empty it will load this variable and show correct html like this:

```
<input name="lastName" id="lastName" autocomplete="off" required="" value="Plaap"/>
```

I just found out that the compilation of the file is indeed the problem.
The attributes in the compiled version seems to lose it's double quotes.

When I alert the compiled version of the page this is what the div looks like in IE8:

```
 <INPUT id=lastName value= name=lastName autocomplete="off" required>
```

this would in HTML in IE8 finally result into:

```
  <input id="lastName" autocomplete="off" required="" value="name=lastName"/>
```

Looking at the same alert in firefox this is what the same input looks like:

```
  <input id="lastName" name="lastName" autocomplete="off" required="" value="" type="text">
```

Here the script for loading the template:

```
 var htmlSource = $(data).html();
 var template = Handlebars.compile(htmlSource);

 //fill template with object or ''
 var compiled = template(OF.address.attributes);
 alert(compiled);

 //now place the completely compiled html into the page
 that.$el.html(compiled);
```

Does anyone here had this problem before or knows how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: create a jsfiddle demonstrating this issue, that would help fellow developers to help you, it would also helps you to abstract bug and fix it.

Comment: Well I haven't encountered same issue, but similar to this. check with your page doctype and while spaces used in template, Try re-arranging attributes as such, it could help you out.

Comment: Hey Ravi, thanks for your reply. I think the scripts are too complicated for a jsfiddle. I am using HTML5 and did re-arrange attributes, this resolved in other attributes turning up in the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after couple of hours finding a solution I found this script: [innerXHTML](http://www.stevetucker.co.uk/innerxhtml.htm)

This works perfectly and does the trick. No more bad fields in IE8.